# Track impedance for CC1101 transceiver

Tags: rf, pcb-design, impedance-matching

I'm trying to make my own board for a [CC1101](http://www.ti.com/product/CC1101) transceiver that will operate at 915 MHz. To do that, I'm just copying the reference design layout from the `eZ430-Chronos-915 RF Access Point` that uses a CC1101 with a MCU to be used as a dongle. This is the reference design PCB, I could only find it in PDF format as an image:

[image]

(Inside the black square are the 0.25 mm tracks and inside the red square is the 0.4 mm track)

And this is the schematic section corresponding to the CC1101:

[image]

By measuring the image I got that the tracks coming out from the `RF_N` and `RF_P` pins are 0.25 mm wide, this is on a two-layer FR4 board with a thickness of 0.8mm, so that will be around 100 Ohm impedance for the tracks which is right because it's a differential signal AFAIK (to maintain 50 Ohm impedance, correct me if I'm wrong please).

These two tracks go to a Balun ([this one](https://ar.mouser.com/datasheet/2/611/0915BM15A0001-242333.pdf)) and the antenna connection is made on pin 1 of the balun. This is the typical layout:

[image]

The balun says the impedance of the track going to pin 1 must be 50 Ohms. I measured that the track that goes out from pin 1 is 0.4 mm wide, with a two-layer, FR4 board with a thickness of 0.8 mm that is an impedance of around 88 Ohms, not even close to 50 Ohms! To get a 50 Ohm impedance the track should be 1.5 mm wide.

What am I missing? I know this design works because I have this board and it works as expected. I was planning to put a 50 Ohm SMA connector in the end, should it then be 50 Ohm or something closer to 88 Ohm?

All the pictures are taken from [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau292g/slau292g.pdf).

Comment: With traces as short as shown and for low frequency as 1 GHz, the small characteristic impedance deviations do not matter.

Comment: And it would be really nice is you could provide actual links to your sources of your pictures and layouts.

Comment: @Ale..chenski Added the link to the PDF!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trace segments in question are just few mm long. For a 1 GHz signal the wavelength is about 160 mm on a typical microstrip on FR4 PCB (~150 ps per inch). Any characteristic impedance imperfections shorter than 1/10th of wavelength has no real effect on signals. So no worry, use the reference designs as-is.

Comment: Just a comment: If lambda/8 can transform an impedance 90 degrees in smith chart, lambda/10 is not so diffent.

Comment: @Mikey, the segments in question are about 3mm long, so you have 3/160 ~ 1/50th of lambda.

Comment: That is true, but i was speaking just in general terms. 1/10th rule is not that a good rule. Maybe shouldn't have commented it in here.

Comment: @Mikey, maybe I shouldn't mention the 1/10th bad rule...